# Angular error - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 4200/main.ts?

Tags: javascript, angular

My Angular website mysteriously broke. I don't recall changing anything. I've even reverted to a working copy in git. This one is really stumping me. I'm getting 404 errors on all my core files including main.ts, styles.css, and all other files I have.

```
http://localhost:4200/styles.css
http://localhost:4200/main.ts
```

Those are examples of files not being found. My styles.css and main.ts are in the same directory as index.html. So I believe that pathing is correct.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

That's how I have it in index.html, also tried ./

I don't understand what could have happened, like I said I didn't change anything..I don't really know where else to look for this error besides in index.html.

Thanks

Comment: That's really weird. Here are some suggestions that might sound obvious but we never know: Make sure that you are actually running the server with ng serve; Make sure you don't have any service worker running; Try a different browser or private/incognito mode to make sure you are not running a cached broken index.html. If all else fail stop the server, clear your node_modules clear the npm cache, and do a clean npm install and try again.

Comment: Have you changed base_href ?

Comment: @FredJohn Thanks, I tried all of those steps and no luck..This is so aggravating!!

Comment: @AnkitKapoor I didnt have a base_href in my index.html. I just tried adding it and didnt work.

Comment: Open console, and check the path for request. What is it?

Comment: @Vitalii `http://localhost:4200/main.ts` is exactly what it's looking for and failing to find. main.ts does exist, and its in the same dir as index.html

Comment: I'd start with a fresh git clone into a new folder and try to run it there.If not, have you tried building the website with ng build, and then using an http server to locally run the build, thus avoiding the angular cli to see if that's the problem? A simple node http server could be installed with "npm install -g http-server". Then stop the cli, create a build with ng build, cmd into /dist and run "http-server -p 4200" and see if it works. Also make sure you haven't modified .angular-cli.json

Comment: Just tried the local server (which is pretty cool, didnt know you could do that) but still didnt work. Got `"GET /main.ts" Error (404): "Not found"
`

Comment: When you do ng build you should end up with a dist folder and bundle.js files, no typescript files. Have you hardcoded main.ts anywhere?

Comment: Well it's working as expected when deployed on SharePoint. Not sure why the http-server -p 4200 doesn't work. So to recap, It works if I build it then deploy it on Sharepoint. Does not work locally if I try to run ng serve